# SQLite and LINQ: 'Member access failed to compile expression' (WHERE Condition)

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Xamarin.Forms page with a ListView that on appearing should be populated with the 5 most recent product dates where the date is today's date. I am using an SQLite database to store the date and time at which a new product is entered into the inventory.

I have a problem with this query in Database.cs:

```
return _database.Table<Product>().OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductDateTime)
       .Where(y => y.ProductDateTime.Date == DateTime.Today).Take(5).ToListAsync();
```

This part of the query is causing an error:

```
Where(y => y.ProductDateTime.Date == DateTime.Today)
```

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Member access failed to compile expression'

I have tried to solve this by trying to use ToList() / ToListAsync().

```
var item = _database.Table<Product>().ToListAsync().OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductDateTime).Where(y => y.ProductDateTime.Date == DateTime.Today).Take(5);

return item.ToListAsync();
```

However, this results in a different error:

> Error CS1061  'Task<List>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending' and no accessible extension method 'OrderByDescending' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<List>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Product.cs:

```
public class Product
{ 
     [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public DateTime ProductDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Database.cs:

```
public class Database
{
     readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _database;

     public Database(string dbPath)
     {
            _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            _database.CreateTableAsync<Product>().Wait();
     }

     public Task<List<Product>> GetProductAsync()
     {

          return _database.Table<Product>().OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductDateTime).Where(y => y.ProductDateTime.Date == DateTime.Today).Take(5).ToListAsync();

     }

     public Task<int> SaveProductAsync(Product product)
     {
            return _database.InsertAsync(product);
     }
}
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
static Database database;

public static Database Database
{
            get
            {
                if (database == null)
                {
                    database = new Database(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "product.db3"));
                }
                return database;
            }
}
```

How can I fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Your LINQ provider is not parsing `DateTime.Today` maybe store it in a variable and use that in the `OrderBy` instead. Don't do `ToList`, it will bring the whole table back off the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime fields in the database don't have an eqivalent of `DateTime.Date` property in .NET.
I would try something like this:

```
var yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1); // <-- omit this, if your database doesn't have any rows with ProductDateTime in the future
....
Where(y => y.ProductDateTime > yesterday &&  y.ProductDateTime < tomorrow)
```